# Existence of the MGF of $X_2$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> For $\theta>0$, let $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be an iid sequence of Uniform$(0,
> \theta)$ random variables and we set $X_{(n)}=\max\left(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \right)$.

I have already shown that the density function of $X_{(n)}$ is 
$$f_{X_{(n)}}(x)=\frac{n}{\theta^n}x^{n-1} \ \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<\theta$$

I have also shown (via integration by parts)  that for $n=2$, the MGF of $X_{(2)}$ is 
$$m_{X_{(2)}}(u)=\frac{2}{\theta^2 u}\left(\theta e^{u\theta}-\frac{1}{u} e^{u\theta}+\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

> I now wish to comment on the **existence** of the MGF of $X_{(2)}$

Clearly $u\neq  0$. To be more precise, I think that the MGF of $X_{(2)}$ exists iff $u>0$. But I am not confident in making this claim.

Comment: $$ \int_0^\theta e^{ux} \, n\left( \frac x \theta\right)^{n-1} \, \frac{dx} \theta $$ This is the integral of a bounded continuous function over a bounded interval. So it's a well defined function of $u. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0 \leq X_i \leq \theta $ for all $i$ so $0 \leq X_{(n)} \leq \theta $. Hence $ 0 \leq Ee^{tX} \leq e^{t\theta }$ for all $t \geq 0$ inlcuding $t=0$. For $t<0$ we have $Ee^{tX_{(n)}} \leq 1$. So MMG function exists for all $t \in \mathbb R$.